# Use Mono to run a software that needs Microsoft .NET Framework 4

Tags: software-installation, windows, mono

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 and I would like to run a software that needs Microsoft .NET Framework 4. Therefore, I installed Mono and its packages (mono-devel, mono-complete, referenceassemblies-pcl, ca-certificates-mono, mono-xsp4). I also installed Visual Basic 10.0.

However when I try to run the software with "sudo mono myProgram.exe". My console output the following message :

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: WinForms_SeeInnerException ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetSetting (System.String AppName, System.String Section, System.String Key, System.String Default) [0x00041] in <052f159205d44babb4f17a8e3eeca1f7>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.Luncher..ctor () [0x00059] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[T] (T Instance) [0x000ea] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_Luncher () [0x00000] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00007] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () [0x00010] in <052f159205d44babb4f17a8e3eeca1f7>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00001] in <052f159205d44babb4f17a8e3eeca1f7>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00017] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: WinForms_SeeInnerException ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetSetting (System.String AppName, System.String Section, System.String Key, System.String Default) [0x00041] in <052f159205d44babb4f17a8e3eeca1f7>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.Luncher..ctor () [0x00059] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[T] (T Instance) [0x000ea] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_Luncher () [0x00000] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00007] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () [0x00010] in <052f159205d44babb4f17a8e3eeca1f7>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00001] in <052f159205d44babb4f17a8e3eeca1f7>:0 
  at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00017] in <f204b55308eb41d3acb7c261ef634837>:0
```

I hope you can help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for your help :)